# Microphone setup in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, speech-recognition

On Windows XP, while on the speech control panel, I see that my voice is recognized by my computer when the Microphone is not connected (where is the voice input in such a case, I am using Thinkpad T400) and when I connect the microphone in the micro-phone jack, the voice recognition turns off. I want the opposite behavior, what should I look for and be careful about as not to do any mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lenovo T400 Laptop has Dual Digital Microphones built in.

if you want make use of the external microphone jack, you may have to configure it through the Realtek HD Audio Control Panel (rthdcpl.exe)

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to recognize to your voice when the microphone is not connected.It could be microsoft sam or something like that.Make sure you have connected the pink wire which is for the mic.There are some microphones with black wires you have to insert in the pink slot and since you are using a laptop insert it in the mic slot(usually a mic picture beside the slot).The error which you describe can happen if the mic wire is inserted into the speaker slot(audio out)but such errors are rare.Connect another mic if you can get from your friend and check it,if the problem still persists try reinstalling the sound driver.If the problem still persists there could be a sound card problem but it is the last case.